# Getting : "TypeError: Cannot read property 'Token' of undefined" when compiling fm.liveswitch?

Tags: typescript, undefined, default

The `fm.liveswitch` JS SDK is for both the client and for your own backend 'app server'.
It compiles and runs fine in the frontend thanks to webpack / babel.
The exact same import statement : `import liveswitch from 'fm.liveswitch';` doesn't work on the backend (Node 16).

I get the above error when I try and call `liveswitch.Token.generateClientRegisterToken(params...)`.
The project is a Firebase / React project and so the 'backend' are the cloud functions.
The `tsconfig.json` for the functions dir is the default from firebase with a couple of tweaks.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
     "module": "commonjs",
     "removeComments": true,
     "noImplicitAny": false,
     "noImplicitReturns": true,
     "noUnusedLocals": true,
     "outDir": "lib",
     "sourceMap": true,
     "strict": true,
     "alwaysStrict": true,
     "target": "es2017"
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
     "include": [
       "src"
     ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out : I needed to add this to tsconfig.json's `compilerOptions` :

`"esModuleInterop": true,`

Now the compiled lib doesn't have `.default` tacked on and all is well.
That was about a day of dithering about until stumbling across this most excellent tsconfig property.

new tsconfig.json :

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "outDir": "lib",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "strict": true,
        "alwaysStrict": true,
        "target": "es2017"
    },
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "include": [
        "src"
    ]
}
```